# VB.NET Solution Properties missing "XML Documentation FIle" path option

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.8

For reference - I'm following this documentation and translating it into VB.NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages

When I get to specifying the XML Documentation File I notice that in the Solution properties while C# has a "Build" menu option, VB.NET instead has "Compile".

[image: Compile Image]

This form looks quite different, and I cannot seem to find where to specify the "XML document file". While I am familiar with C#, switching to C# is not an option for this project. I'm stumped on this one, any ideas?

EDIT 1:

I've was able to edit this value in my .vbproj file as `<DocumentationFile>`.

This still does not appear to write the file. I added a properly formed XML file to the intended location, and while my application now executes happily my comments are not being written to the file. So something is still amiss here.

EDIT 2:

Quasi-solution, it appears to ignore my edit to .vbproj, but DOES output an XML file to `~/bin/XmlDocument.xml`. I cannot find a way to edit this name or path but it appears to be consistent between debug/release/publish builds, so it'll do for now.

Answer (score 1):

This explains, among other things, where the XML documentation file is.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/documenting-your-code-with-xml

Comment: I've read through this, but doesn't appear to be related to the question?

Comment: @JacobM. - the reference I provided says what you apparently found out, your edit 2.

Comment: I am trying to find the setting that defines the file path, not the file path itself.